# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails mysql php

Tags: mysql

I am getting a

> "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`smarturbia`.`pois`, CONSTRAINT `fk_pois_cities1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`city`) REFERENCES `cities` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO
>   ACTION) (1509)"

and i have no idea why.

My tables are generated through Mysql workbench 5.2, if you need the rest of the tables let me know :

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `smarturbia`.`cities`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `smarturbia`.`cities` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `smarturbia`.`cities` (
  `id` BIGINT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `published` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `open` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `path` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'taxi' ,
  `key` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `world` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'earth' ,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `description` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `logo` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `footer` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '/taxi/assets/img/taxi_smarturbia_image_default.png' ,
  `footer_large` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL ,
  `leftpub` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `rightpub` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `model` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL ,
  `modelxscale` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '1' ,
  `modelyscale` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '1' ,
  `modelzscale` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '1' ,
  `wheelmodelxscale` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '1' ,
  `wheelmodelyscale` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '1' ,
  `wheelmodelzscale` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '1' ,
  `allwheels` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `frontleftwheel` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `frontrightwheel` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `rearleftwheel` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `rearrightwheel` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `axisdistance` FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT '2.5' ,
  `wheelsdistance` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '1' ,
  `wheelsheight` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '1' ,
  `kms` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `maxspeed` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '160' ,
  `accel` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '25' ,
  `accelstep` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '25' ,
  `minaccelstep` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '5' ,
  `maxrevspeed` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '30' ,
  `decel` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '90' ,
  `gravity` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '70' ,
  `camheight` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '5' ,
  `camtilt` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '90' ,
  `traildistance` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '15' ,
  `mass` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '3000' ,
  `vehicleagility` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '0.0005' ,
  `suspensionstiffness` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '0.5' ,
  `suspensionrestlength` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '0.5' ,
  `suspensiondamping` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '-0.15' ,
  `suspensiondeltatime` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '0.25' ,
  `turnspeedmin` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '20' ,
  `turnspeedmax` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '60' ,
  `speedmaxturn` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '5' ,
  `speedminturn` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '50' ,
  `steerroll` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '-1' ,
  `rollspring` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '0.5' ,
  `rollclamp` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '50' ,
  `mapiconurl` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `vehicleshadow` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `vehiclesound` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `vehiclesoundtime` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '150' ,
  `vehiclefastsound` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `vehiclefastsoundtime` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '150' ,
  `backgroundsound` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `backgroundsoundtime` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '150' ,
  `crashsound` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `crashsoundtime` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '150' ,
  `vehicletype` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'car' ,
  `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `key` (`key` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 153
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `smarturbia`.`pois`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `smarturbia`.`pois` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `smarturbia`.`pois` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `city` BIGINT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  `description` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL ,
  `lat` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `lon` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `heading` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_pois_cities1_idx` (`city` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pois_cities1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`city` )
    REFERENCES `smarturbia`.`cities` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 408
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

Comment: This obviously comes from the execution of an INSERT or an UPDATE query. Can you post it, please ?

Comment: There is a problem with data. Fix data firstly.

Answer (score 2):

Insert the values in the table in which your primary key is defined..Then try to insert in the table in which you having the foreign key...

I think you are inserting the values in the table of foreign key without inserting in the table having primary key..
  It is not recommended but you can try this

```
                           set foreign_key_checks=0;
```

To enable foreign key checking

```
                       set foreign_key_checks=1;
```